# VBA dictionary and class module

Tags: excel, vba, dictionary

The code breaks here

ws.Cells(j, "M").Value = dict(ws.Cells(j, "H").Value).volume

ws.Cells(j, "N").Value = dict(ws.Cells(j, "H").Value).rate

I believe the issue is trying to retrieve the dictionary value when the key is dynamic so

dict(ws.Cells(j, "H").Value).volume errors out
but
dict(5455).volume

will work.

Am I correct that this is the issue and any solutions?

```
Sub RetrieveData()

Dim dict As New Dictionary
Dim group As clsgroup
Dim lrowRetrieve As Long, lrowLookup As Long
Dim ws As Worksheet
Dim i As Long, j As Long, name As String, rate As Long, volume As Long

lrowRetrieve = Cells(Rows.Count, "C").End(xlUp).Row
lrowLookup = Cells(Rows.Count, "H").End(xlUp).Row
Set ws = Sheets("Test")
dict.RemoveAll

    For i = 1 To lrowRetrieve
    'add criteria for month/year of reporting

      If ws.Cells(i, "C").Value <> "" And ws.Cells(i, "C").Value <> 0 And ws.Cells(i, "G").Value <> "" And ws.Cells(i, "G").Value <> 0 Then
          name = ws.Cells(i, "C").Value

        If dict.Exists(name) = False Then
          Set group = New clsgroup
          group.name = name
          dict.Add key:=group.name, Item:=group
        Else
            Set group = dict(name)
        'dict(ws.Cells(i, "C").Value) = ws.Cells(i, "G").Value
        End If
      
        With group
          .rate = .rate + ws.Cells(i, "F").Value
          .volume = .volume + ws.Cells(i, "G").Value
        End With
      End If
    Next i

Dim key As Variant
For Each key In dict
    Set group = dict(key)
    With group
    Debug.Print .name, .rate, .volume
    End With
Next key


    For j = 25 To lrowLookup
    
        Select Case ws.Cells(j, "H").Value
        Case "5455"
            If ws.Cells(j, "K").Value = "Medical" Then
                ws.Cells(j, "M").Value = dict("5455/5456").volume
                ws.Cells(j, "N").Value = dict("5455/5456").rate
            Else
                ws.Cells(j, "M").Value = dict("5455/5456 (non med)").volume
                ws.Cells(j, "N").Value = dict("5455/5456 (non med)").rate
            End If
        Case Else
            Debug.Print ws.Cells(j, "H").Value
            ws.Cells(j, "M").Value = dict(ws.Cells(j, "H").Value).volume
            ws.Cells(j, "N").Value = dict(ws.Cells(j, "H").Value).rate
        End Select
       
    Next j
End Sub
```

Answer (score 0):

`dict(5455)` is not the same as `dict("5455")` - it matters what data type your keys have when they're added - reliable retrieval from the dictionary requires the same type be used....

You might find it best to always convert your keys to String before adding them, and always retrieve with String-type keys

```vb
Sub Tester()

    Dim dict As Object
    Set dict = CreateObject("scripting.dictionary")
    
    dict(5455) = "Numeric"
    dict("5455") = "String"  '"5455" is a different key from 5455 !
    
    Debug.Print dict(5455)   '>> "Numeric"
    Debug.Print dict("5455") '>> "String"
    
End Sub
```