# Adding missing file names from directory to Excel column (VBA)

Tags: excel, vba, spreadsheet

I am trying to write a VBA macro to automatically update an excel column (E) of filenames representing a directory (C:\Directory) with any files (mostly pdf) that might have been added to that directory. This is the code I have so far:

```
Sub GetFileNames()
   Dim sPath As String
   Dim sFile As String
   Dim Cl As Range
   Dim Nme As String
   
   'specify directory
   sPath = "C:\Directory\"
   With CreateObject("scripting.dictionary")
      For Each Cl In Range("E3", Range("E" & Rows.Count).End(xlUp))
         .Item(Cl.Value) = Empty
      Next Cl

      sFile = Dir(sPath)
      Do While sFile <> ""
         Nme = CreateObject("Scripting.FileSystemObject").GetBaseName(sFile)
         If Not .exists(Nme) Then
            Range("E" & Rows.Count).End(xlUp).Offset(1).Value = Nme
         End If
         sFile = Dir ' Get next filename
      Loop
   End With
End Sub
```

Unforunatly I am not recieving the expected result. Instead of all missing files being added to the bottom of the column, only one file is added at a time when running the macro. It also adds files that are already in the column (Marked red in the screenshot below). Thanks for the help!

[Image showing faulty cells being added](https://i.stack.imgur.com/Fwtak.png)

Comment: It's a side note, but I'd move the `CreateObject("Scripting.FileSystemObject")` outside the loop, e.g. `Dim FSO As Object`, `Set FSO = CreateObject("Scripting.FileSystemObject")`, then use `FSO.GetBaseName` within the loop.

Comment: **Unable to recreate.** The code as is creates a listing of file basenames in column E as required. Some files will be ignored if two files have same basename but different suffix, of course. If a new file is added, this is picked up on next run. If files are removed, they remain on list. BigBen's comments improve code but do not change result.

Comment: I would suggest stepping through the code a line at a time to watch the logic play out and see where your code is tripping up.

Comment: Have you tried `.Item(CStr(Cl.Value)) = Empty` since you're dealing with numeric filenames?

Comment: Since your filenames are a mix of numeric values and text values, it might be a good idea to format that column as Text, to avoid the problem pointed to by @VBasic2008: dictionary keys are *type-sensitive*, so a numeric-typed key of `999` will not be matched by `dict.exists("999")`  Previously: https://stackoverflow.com/a/72778402/478884

Comment: @VBasic2008 Thank you! That seems to have fixed the issue with files being added to the column even though they where already there. Unfortunatly it still only adds one file name per run of the macro and not all that are missing.